# iDangerous Swiper plugin reset slides

Tags: swiper.js

I am using the iDangerous Swiper plugin. I need to periodically change all the slides in an ajax method. What would be the best method to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

- call `destroy()` on Swiper
- remove/replace all you slides with new ones
- clear `style` attribute on `.swiper-wrapper`
- initialize swiper again