# iDangerous Swiper, subsequent destroy() and reInit() methods

Tags: jquery, carousel, swiper.js

According to the directions provided as an answer here...

[iDangerous Swiper plugin reset slides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394521/idangerous-swiper-plugin-reset-slides)

I'm trying to do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/monastic/ydKn2/17/

```
<div id="slide-repo">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff.jpg" />
    </div>
    ...................   
</div>

<div>
    <button id="update-slides">Update Slides</button>
</div>

<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/ff0000/fff.jpg" />
        </div>   
        .................
    </div>
</div>


var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
     mode: 'vertical', 
     loop: true,
     loopAdditionalSlides: 5,
     centeredSlides: true,
     slidesPerView: 2,
     initialSlide: 0,
 });

$('button#update-slides').on('click', function(){

    var swiperWrapper = $('.swiper-wrapper'),
        newSlides = $('#slide-repo').children('.swiper-slide').clone(true);

    mySwiper.destroy();
    swiperWrapper.empty().append(newSlides);
    $('.swiper-wrapper').attr('style', '');
    mySwiper.reInit();

});
```

But console is returning 'Cannot read property 'init' of null'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is because you're calling `mySwiper.destroy()` and therefore can't run `reInit()`. The documentation says reInit is for resetting when you've added or removed slides. But here you're calling reInit on an element that is no longer a swiper.

Instead, you could re-create the swiper each time. (I'm not sure why just calling `removeAllSlides` then `reInit` does not keep the same settings.)

```
  var settings = {
    mode: 'vertical', 
    loop: true,
    loopAdditionalSlides: 5,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 2,
    initialSlide: 0,
  },
  mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', settings);

$('button#update-slides').on('click', function(){

    var swiperWrapper = $('.swiper-wrapper'),
        newSlides = $('#slide-repo').children('.swiper-slide').clone(true);

    mySwiper.destroy();
    swiperWrapper.empty().append(newSlides);
    $('.swiper-wrapper').attr('style', '');
    mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', settings);

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L2HJK/2/

Comment: This is probably on the right track, but you'll see in your fiddle that the re-initialized swiper isn't functional with regard to loop mode. I suspect the solution probably does involve a destroy() call, but I'm having a hard time seeing how this would work for a highly dynamic slider, destroy-ing and reinit-ing with multiple successions..

Comment: Interesting. You're right, I didn't notice that the settings didn't carry over. You can always re-create it after destroying it, with the same settings: http://jsfiddle.net/L2HJK/2/  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh, that looks like it! Hmm, I must've been overthinking this somewhere...but excellent, thanks!